# Getting warning "TimeSeries broadcasting along DataFrame index by default is deprecated"

Tags: python, error-handling, module, pandas

I am using Python 2.7 and keep getting the below error. Please let me know if you need the full code but it is a bit long. Thank you for your help.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3619
FutureWarning)
FutureWarning: TimeSeries broadcasting along DataFrame index by default is deprecated.     
Please use DataFrame.<op> to explicitly broadcast arithmetic operations along the index
```

here is the class Portfolio

```
class Portfolio(object):
"""An abstract base class representing a portfolio of 
positions (including both instruments and cash), determined
on the basis of a set of signals provided by a Strategy."""

__metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

@abc.abstractmethod
def generate_positions(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("Should implement generate_positions()!")

@abc.abstractmethod
def backtest_portfolio(self):
    raise NotImplementedError("Should implement backtest_portfolio()!")
```

here is the code that is causing the issue in the <<<< if **name** == "**main**"

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from pandas.io.data import DataReader
from backtest import Strategy, Portfolio

class MovingAverageCrossStrategy(Strategy):

def __init__(self, symbol, bars, short_window=8, long_window=50):
    self.symbol = symbol
    self.bars = bars

    self.short_window = short_window
    self.long_window = long_window

def generate_signals(self):
    signals = pd.DataFrame(index=self.bars.index)
    signals['signal'] = 0.0

    # Create the set of short and long simple moving averages over the 
    # respective periods
    signals['short_mavg'] = pd.rolling_mean(bars['Close'], self.short_window, min_periods=1)
    signals['long_mavg'] = pd.rolling_mean(bars['Close'], self.long_window, min_periods=1)

    # Create a 'signal' (invested or not invested) when the short moving average crosses the long
    # moving average, but only for the period greater than the shortest moving average window
    signals['signal'][self.short_window:] = np.where(signals['short_mavg'][self.short_window:]
                                                     > signals['long_mavg'][self.short_window:], 1.0, 0.0)   

    # Take the difference of the signals in order to generate actual trading orders
    signals['positions'] = signals['signal'].diff()   

    return signals

class MarketOnClosePortfolio(Portfolio):

def __init__(self, symbol, bars, signals, initial_capital=100000.0):
    self.symbol = symbol        
    self.bars = bars
    self.signals = signals
    self.initial_capital = float(initial_capital)
    self.positions = self.generate_positions()

def generate_positions(self):
    positions = pd.DataFrame(index=signals.index).fillna(0.0)
    positions[self.symbol] = 100*signals['signal']   # This strategy buys 100 shares
    return positions

def backtest_portfolio(self):
    portfolio = self.positions*self.bars['Close']
    pos_diff = self.positions.diff()

    portfolio['holdings'] = (self.positions*self.bars['Close']).sum(axis=1)
    portfolio['cash'] = self.initial_capital - (pos_diff*self.bars['Close']).sum(axis=1).cumsum()

    portfolio['total'] = portfolio['cash'] + portfolio['holdings']
    portfolio['returns'] = portfolio['total'].pct_change()
    return portfolio

if __name__ == "__main__":
# Obtain daily bars of stock from Yahoo Finance for the period
# 1st Jan 1990 to 1st Jan 2014 - This is an example from ZipLine
symbol = 'AAPL'
bars = DataReader(symbol, "yahoo", datetime.datetime(1990,1,1), datetime.datetime(2014,1,1))

# Create a Moving Average Cross Strategy instance with a short moving
# average window of 8 days and a long window of 50 days
mac = MovingAverageCrossStrategy(symbol, bars, short_window=8, long_window=50)
signals = mac.generate_signals()

# Create a portfolio of stock, with $100,000 initial capital
portfolio = MarketOnClosePortfolio(symbol, bars, signals, initial_capital=100000.0)
returns = portfolio.backtest_portfolio()
```

Comment: 1) Please trim the code down to something that reproduces the warning and is *not* too long 2) what's your question?

Comment: hi paul, i guess my issue is, why is this error occurring and how to understand the error.

Comment: I'm happy to help, but I don't have time to go through that good. please boil it down to a few lines that generate your pandas objects and perform the operation that generates the warning. Doing so will make it easier for other to help and for others to fix their own problems when they encounter this down the road.

Comment: for instance, the error you're seeing has nothing to do with plotting, so cut that stuff out.

Comment: See this section in the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html?highlight=broadcasting#data-alignment-and-arithmetic for an explanation of why you get the warning. Previsouly when eg adding a dataframe with a datetimeindex and a series with a datetimeindex, it would align on the index (instead of the columns as other dataframes). This is not deprecated and you should use a dedicated method.

Comment: i will get on that right away and see where the issue is happening.. really appreciate the step by step to try and solve this! be back shortly

Comment: just figured out the issue, see above for new code

Comment: you removed all of the pandas operations -- this code doesn't run at all. we need an self-contained example. see this: http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: the edits have been made to a condensed version. see above and thanks again

Comment: Can you indicate which line in your code triggers the warning? You should normally be able to see this in the warning traceback.

Comment: literally the last two cause the issue, but I included the class Portfolio and the Marketonclose class as well

Comment: No, the traceback will point to an exact line somewhere in one of the functions. Can you give that? Then it will be easier to say why you get the warning.

Comment: here it is  Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3619
FutureWarning)
FutureWarning: TimeSeries broadcasting along DataFrame index by default is deprecated.     
Please use DataFrame.<op> to explicitly broadcast arithmetic operations along the index

Comment: Ah, maybe I am used to the more detailed tracebacks in IPython. And it seems that warnings are not that detailed as errors

Answer (score 6):

Without being able to run your code, it is difficult to point to the exact reason, but take for example this line in `generate_positions`:

```
portfolio = self.positions*self.bars['Close']
```

And supposing `self.positions` is a DataFrame, and `self.bars['Close']` is a Series (in this case a column of a DataFrame, which is returned as a Series). I try to explain the issue with a toy example:

First generating a dataframe and a series (with a datetimeindex):

```
In [3]: idx = pd.date_range('2012-01-01', periods=3)
In [5]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3], 'B':[10,20,30]}, index=idx)
In [6]: df
Out[6]: 
            A   B
2012-01-01  1  10
2012-01-02  2  20
2012-01-03  3  30

In [7]: s = pd.Series([1,2,3], index=idx)
In [8]: s
Out[8]: 
2012-01-01    1
2012-01-02    2
2012-01-03    3
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Now if we multiply both, we will get the warning you noticed:

```
In [10]: df * s
/home/joris/scipy/pandas-np16/pandas/core/frame.py:2920: FutureWarning: TimeSeries 
broadcasting along DataFrame index by default is deprecated. Please use DataFrame.<op> 
to explicitly broadcast arithmetic operations along the index
  FutureWarning)
Out[10]: 
            A   B
2012-01-01  1  10
2012-01-02  4  40
2012-01-03  9  90
```

This is because of what I mentioned in the comments and is explained here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html?highlight=broadcasting#data-alignment-and-arithmetic. Normally if a dataframe and series are multiplied, the series is broadcasted over the columns, while for timeserieses this is done over the rows. But this is deprecated.
So instead you should use an equivalent operator as the warnings advices. In case of a multiplication:

```
In [13]: df.mul(s, axis=0)
Out[13]: 
            A   B
2012-01-01  1  10
2012-01-02  4  40
2012-01-03  9  90
```

So for each operator (+, *; <, >, /, etc) there is an equivalent method. See here for the list of methods: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#id4 [url updated]

---

To show what is meant with 'broadcasted over the columns', another example:

```
In [14]: s2 = pd.Series([10, 100],  index=['A', 'B'])

In [15]: s2
Out[15]: 
A     10
B    100
dtype: int64

In [16]: df * s2
Out[16]: 
             A     B
2012-01-01  10  1000
2012-01-02  20  2000
2012-01-03  30  3000
```

So as you can see, each element of the series is matched with one column, and the whole column is then multiplied with that value. While in the case of the timeseries, each element of the series was matched with a row.

Comment: joris - great explanation. Since this is still new to me, I understand what you are trying to say. Its basically a difference in how the multiplication occurs for a dataframe vs a series... Now, are you also suggesting that by changing the operator function to something like '''DataFrame.mul(other[, axis, level, fill_value])''' then this might fix the issue?

Comment: Yes, so if you change all occurences of +, -, *, /, <, >, etc where you have a dataframe and a series to the corresponding method, this will fix the issue (the warning, as for now it will give the same result. But in the future this will be changed, and only the method will still work).